# Mongodb/mongoose models value/typeof is Object instead of Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a Spotify clone. When a new user registers for the site i'ld like to create a playlist for them titled Liked Songs and add it to the array of playlists associated with this user.  So far I've been able to create the playlist but unable to add it to the Users array of playlists.  When I have tried to add the newly created/saved playlist to the User.playlists array, I came across an issue because instead of User.playlists being an array (as intended as specified in the model) it console logs as an Object.

Whats going on and how do I correct this?

The plan is to have the playlist info (title, author, image, songs) stored directly in the User instance but the songs array in each instance of a playlist will be referenced by the song ids.

FULL PROJECT [here](https://github.com/greenHermes/PlaylistifyExpress)

function that creates first playlist and route where it is used
[image: creating first and default playlist upon registering]

User Model, where playlist is declared an array
[image: user model]

console.logs from function that automatically creates first playlist upon registering
[image: console logs]

Comment: Hard to follow your screenshots, but just as an FYI, arrays in JS are objects so don't be surprised to see `console.log(typeof []);` print `object`. If you want to check if something is an array, you need `console.log(Array.isArray([]))`.

Comment: @codemonkey. Thank you, this helped.